Do violations of the rules of war by one side justify the other?
I recall reading, that Geneva conventions -- or some other international agreements regarding the rules of war -- had explicit text somewhere stating, that violations by one side do not allow the other side(s) to violate them (except for specific rules -- like shooting at ambulances, if the enemy uses them for fighting).
But now I need an actual citation and cannot find it! Could someone, please, help? A direct link to the actual text would be best, but something like "Article Foo" or "Protocol Bar" may work too.
Note: the supposed duplicate is not a duplicate at all:

It talks about a particular case of Perfidy, whereas I'm asking a general question.
It offers no general citations, which is, what I'm requesting.

